# C# WebBrowser HTML with references to scripts and images

Tags: c#, .net, webserver, resources, href

I'm writing a C# app using the WebBrowser control, and I want all content I display to come from embedded resources - not static local files, and not remote files.

Setting the initial text of the control to an embedded HTML file works great with this code inspired by [this post](http://blog.topholt.com/2008/03/18/c-trick-load-embedded-resources-in-a-class-library/):

```
browser.DocumentText=loadResourceText("myapp.index.html");

private string loadResourceText(string name)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name);
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    String myText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    return myText;
}
```

As good as that is, files referred to in the HTML - javascript, images like `<img src="whatever.png"/>` etc, don't work. I found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72103/how-do-i-reference-a-local-resource-in-generated-html-in-winforms-webbrowser-co#273840) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/webbrowser-control-from-net-how-to-inject-javascript), but neither is asking *exactly* what  I mean, namely referring to *embedded* resources in the exe, not files.

I tried `res://...` and using a `<base href='..."` but neither seemed to work (though I may have not got it right).

Perhaps (following my own suggestion on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72103/how-do-i-reference-a-local-resource-in-generated-html-in-winforms-webbrowser-co#273840)), using a little embedded C# webserver is the only way... but I would have thought there is some trick to get this going?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can see three ways to get this going:

1: write the files you need to flat files in the temp area, navigate the `WebBrowser` to the html file, and delete them once the page has loaded

2: as you say, an embedded web-server - herhaps `HttpListener` - but note that this uses HTTP.SYS, and so requires admin priveleges (or you need to [pre-open the port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169904/))

3: like 1, but using named-pipe server to avoid writing a file

I have to say, the first is a lot simpler and requires zero configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// Hi try this may help u.
private string CheckImages(ExtendedWebBrowser browser)
{
      StringBuilder builderHTML = new StringBuilder(browser.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml);
      ProcessURLS(browser, builderHTML, "img", "src");                
      ProcessURLS(browser, builderHTML, "link", "href");
      // ext...

      return builderHTML.ToString();

}

private static void ProcessURLS(ExtendedWebBrowser browser, StringBuilder builderHTML, string strLink, string strHref)
{
     for (int k = 0; k < browser.Document.Body.Parent.GetElementsByTagName(strLink).Count; k++)
     {
          string strURL = browser.Document.Body.Parent.GetElementsByTagName(strLink)[k].GetAttribute(strHref);
          string strOuterHTML = browser.Document.Body.Parent.GetElementsByTagName(strLink)[k].OuterHtml;
          string[] strlist = strOuterHTML.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
          StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
          for (int p = 0; p < strlist.Length; p++)
          {
              if (strlist[p].StartsWith(strHref))                        
                  builder.Append (strlist[p].Contains("http")? strlist[p] + " ":
                      (strURL.StartsWith("http") ?  strHref + "=" + strURL + " ":
                           strHref + "= " + "http://xyz.com" + strURL + " " ));                           
              else
                  builder.Append(strlist[p] + " ");
          }

          builderHTML.Replace(strOuterHTML, builder.ToString());
      }
}
```