# How can i display stored html codes in webbrowser control in C# windows form application without creating html files on hard drive?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a database which has stored HTML code sources for different articles which are not in similar HTML design pattern. I want to display these codes in windows form application control e.g WebBrowser control so that it can be displayed in its original HTMLdesign style as if in the browser.But i hope if this process doesn't include creating html files on hard drive to read from it and i wish if there is a way to make the WebBrowser control navigate from objects created in the memory not created on hard drive .. 
For example  i wish if the code could be like this :

```
HTMLFile myfile = new HTML File (htmlcode);
webbrowser1.Navigate(myfile);
```

Comment: Just be careful if you are letting users put html into your database. You don't want to open yourself up to scripting attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the `DocumentText` property of the `WebBrowser` control.

For example:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body><h1>This is a test</h1></body></html>";
```

See this post for more info: 
[C# WebBrowser HTML with references to scripts and images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274315/c-webbrowser-html-with-references-to-scripts-and-images)