# How to set HTML Image Source as c# Resource Image in WebBrowser Control in Winform Application

Tags: c#, html, .net, webbrowser-control

I am doing something like this , i know this code is incorrect ...

```
string strSrc = Namespace.Properties.Resources.images.ToString();

        webBrowser1.DocumentText = @" <img src=""+strSrc+"" />";
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: How to set Image source

Comment: Can you please refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72103/how-do-i-reference-a-local-resource-in-generated-html-in-winforms-webbrowser-con) and see.

Comment: i have visited this post but not understand perfectly any answer. Do you modify my code ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code..

String ExactPath = Path.GetFullPath(Namespace.Properties.Resources.images.image1.jpg);

webBrowser1.DocumentText = @" ";